# Opencart Modification Refresh Mysql

Tags: opencart-3

I am using **OpenCart 3.0.3.6** and trying to get an extension working. There were no errors until the extension developer emailed me about my modification refresh is broken.

I tried to refresh modification and all my admin login and page become no js no css template. I tried to clean all files, so I did was created a new local server and added only my SQL.

All files are from original **OpenCart 3.0.3.6** and my site still seems like this. So how can I save my SQL. Thank you very much if there is missing information please ask sorry about misspell. [image: You can see here]

Comment: The problem seems a template issue. I menage to go behind this in short-term, still can't find proper way to fix. Issue caused by twig.php.